# Xcode 4.3 for Snow Leopard

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xcode4.3

Xcode 4.3 was released some days ago, but there's only a version for Lion:
https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action

Is Xcode 4.3 compatible with Snow Leopard?

Comment: XCode 4.3 is not compatible with SL. Apple forget about SL.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/00-Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: According to that link from Apple's documentation, in the compatibility section, it states: "Xcode requires a Mac running Mac OS X 10.7.2 or later, and includes iOS SDK 5.0, and Mac OS X SDK 10.7 and 10.6."

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's unlikely that you will get this version of Xcode running on Snow Leopard. Apple like their developers to keep up-to-date with the latest operating systems, so will drop support for the previous OS after a while. I think Lion has been out long enough now that Apple will deprecate support for Snow Leopard.

Answer (score 3):

No. You cannot use it on snow leopard because it's minimum requirement is mac os x 10.7.3 or later.

Answer (score 3):

No there is not, I am hoping there will be one available soon.