# Xcode 4.3 available for snow-leopard

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, osx-snow-leopard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Xcode 4.3 for Snow Leopard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9377467/xcode-4-3-for-snow-leopard)

Do we have Xcode 4.3 available for snow-leopard? I am on Xcode 4.2 & wanted to run on iOS 5.1.

Comment: As far as I know, Xcode 4.3 is for Lion only... sadly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No - XCode 4.2 is the last version that will be available for Snow Leopard. You will need to update to Lion (as I have just had to for the same reason).

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid no.  For as long as I've been writing iOS apps, Apple has compelled developers to keep their Mac OS up-to-date if they wish to code for the latest iOS builds.  To build for iOS 5.1 you'll need [Xcode 4.3.1](http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/) - which is Lion only. Personally, I think it's the best development environment I've ever worked in, so it's hard to complain too loudly.